# How do I create a new column in SQL that displays the total average for another field in each row?

Tags: sql, sql-server, average

I'd like to figure out how I can insert a column average as a NEW field in SSMS. Let me use the following table as an example:

```
Style |   Car    | Sales
------|----------|-------
Sedan | Civic    | $100
Sedan | Accord   | $200
SUV   | CR-V     | $150
SUV   | Odyssey  | $150
```

The average of this table is $150 {AVG(Sales)}

What I want to know, is how can I create a new View that inserts this average as a new column? The view would looks something like this:

```
Style |   Car    | Sales | Avg Sales
------|----------|-------|-----------
Sedan | Civic    | $100  | $150
Sedan | Accord   | $200  | $150
SUV   | CR-V     | $150  | $150
SUV   | Odyssey  | $150  | $150
```

I've done some significant searching, as I thought this would be a simple operation. However, I'm only able to find information on how to group averages or how to display the average.

Comment: SMSS, SSMS, MySQL... Which dbms are you actually using?

Comment: Use a subquery to calculate the AVG. cross join.

Comment: Do you REALLY have a `$` sign in the `Sales` column?

Comment: And each time when this average changes you want to recalculate the whole table???

Comment: @Akina, OP says "create a new _view_".

Comment: @jarlh Sorry, I am using SSMS, still new to the SQL world. Would you mind breaking down your subquery explanation more? I'm confused how this would work. Thanks!

Comment: Once upon a time this was a somewhat difficult thing to do. Newer versions of SQL do allow for window functions precisely for these queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use window functions:

```
create view myview as
select
    t.*,
    avg(sales) over(partition by style) avg_sales
from mytable t
```

If you want the average of the whole table, then:

```
create view myview as
select
    t.*,
    avg(sales) over() avg_sales
from mytable t
```

Comment: Hi @GMB, thanks for your help! However, I do not want to partition on anything. This is where my confusion comes from, as I would like to use the whole table when calculating an average in a new column

Comment: @Arizona72: in this case you can use an empty `over()` clause - see my updated answer.

Comment: okay that makes sense! Thanks so much for your help! Sometimes it can be hard to even figure out what I want to ask .